# How can I concatenate vectors in loop in R

Tags: r, string, loops, concatenation

everyone

I brought some new trivial questions to ask. I've searched, but I failed to look for the most efficient answer.

The string(or list) I would like to make looks like:

```
c("who","expr1","who","expr2",...,"who","expr100")
```

How can I efficiently make this string using loop(or another function) in R?

Thank you~!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least this is one choice:

```
c(rbind("who", paste0("expr", 1:100)))
```